# What does impedance in datasheets mean?

Tags: impedance

Can anyone explain impedance in a datasheet? What does this mean:

> (50 uH + 5 ohm) || 50 ohm

Line impedance stabilization network (LISN). Like this one : [schwarzbeck.de/Datenblatt/k8124.pdf](http://schwarzbeck.de/Datenblatt/k8124.pdf).

Comment: The data sheet for what? What kind of impedance? Input impedance? Output impedance? Transfer impedance? Characteristic impedance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you post the datasheet that you're reading I could answer it with more confidence, but what you wrote here can be read as a \$50 \ \mathrm{\mu H}\$ inductance in series with a \$ 5 \ \Omega\$ resistance and all that in parallel with a \$50 \ \Omega\$ resistance. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDrLUH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I undeleted this because it appears to be a good answer